# Xcode fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented by subclassing SKSpritenode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I do not know how I am getting this error.  I have created a class called item that inherits NSObject and NSCoding.  This class decode and encodes a SKSpritenode.  I decided that I wanted to have more complicated items so I made a class that subclasses from SKSpritenode that has some extra functionality.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class SpecialNodes: SKSpriteNode {
    private var textAtlas: SKTextureAtlas
    private var imageUniformName: String
    init(Begintexture: SKTexture!, textAtlas: SKTextureAtlas, uniformName: String) {
        self.textAtlas = textAtlas
        let texture = Begintexture
        self.imageUniformName = uniformName
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: (texture?.size())!)
        print(Begintexture)

        animateTextures(atlas: textAtlas)

    }

    convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func animateTextures(atlas: SKTextureAtlas) {
        let pacAtlas = atlas
        var frames = [SKTexture]()

        let numImages = pacAtlas.textureNames.count

        for i in 1...numImages/2 {
            let textName = "\(imageUniformName)\(i)"
            frames.append(pacAtlas.textureNamed(textName))
        }

        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: 0.1)

        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([animation,animation.reversed()])))

    }

}
```

This gives me an error fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented. I am guessing when this subclass of SKSpritenode is being decoded in the item class? I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Your `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method calls `fatalError` - don't do this if you don't want to crash.  Replace this with a call to `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`

Comment: Are yo placing this object in a sks file inside of the Scene Editor?

Comment: No I am not placing it in a sks file